# FStream C++ automatic line addition

Tags: c++, fstream

It is a pain to do an endline between each value with OFSTREAM.
Here's an example of what I've got:

```
    ofstream fout("~/xample.txt");
    fout << val1;
    fout << endl;
    fout << val2;
```

I want to be able to do, instead,

```
    ofstream fout("xample.txt");
    fout << val1;
    fout << val2;
```

I don't care how the file is stored because I will write a configuration wizard anyways.

Comment: I don't think it's impossible. With some trickery you *could* fit your stream with a customized stream buffer that inserts a newline after each insertion.

Answer (score 2):

If `fout << val1 << endl;` does not work with you, you might be able to inherit ofstream and create your own stream that adds `endl` automatically. But also you can drink water from fire hydrant.

Comment: Do you know how to do that? I am still kinda new to C++, and I have to store 100 values!

Comment: @yash101 I do not know that, I am pretty sure you do not want to know that. Just learn loops and arrays, I am sure you will find what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

> It is a pain ...

Besides you could simply write

```
fout << val1 << endl;
fout << val2 << endl;
```

you may use any other whitespace character value to delimit your values in the output file:

```
fout << val1 << ' ';
fout << val2 << ' ';
// ... more value outputs
fout << endl;
```

Shouldn't matter for the file size, but number of lines definitely.

**UPDATE:**
As you're asking how to extend the formatting behavior on `std::ostream`:
I don't think it's a good idea to use inheritance from `std::streambuf`, `std::ostream`, et al., and try to (re-)implement the interfaces themselves (as usually never it's a good idea inheriting STL classes, can be done though). I'd say the intended way is to use stream manipulators for such.

To automate appending the `endl` or any other delimiter you could write a small parameterized stream manipulator (at least this solution is copy/paste and IDE intellisense friendly):

```
template<typename T>
class auto_delim_manip
{
public:
    auto_delim_manip(T value_, char delim_) 
    : value(value_) 
    , delim(delim_) {}
    void put(std::ostream& os) const {
        os << value << delim;
        os.flush();
    }
private:
    T value;
    char delim;
};

template<typename T>
auto_delim_manip<T> auto_delim(T value, char delim = '\n') {
    return auto_delim_manip<T>(value,delim);
}

template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const auto_delim_manip<T>& autoDelim) 
{
    autoDelim.put(os);
    return os;
}
```

---

```
int main() {

    cout << auto_delim(5.2) << auto_delim(3) << auto_delim("Hello!");

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
5.2
3
Hello!
```

Check the [running sample here](http://ideone.com/AgSstv).

Comment: That aught to work, but I wished there was a way to do this automatically!

Comment: @yash101 _'... to do this automatically!'_ What exactly do you mean? To have written values delimited automatically?

Comment: What I mean is how do I create a class with a similar interface? I am still learning C++. Please point me to a tutorial if you know of one! ;)

Comment: @yash101 _'What I mean is how do I create a class with a similar interface?'_ No, you don't need to do so, see my updates please.

Comment: @yash101 As for your other comments, that you'll need to _stroe 100 values or more_, **why** are you using distinct variables for all the values?? Using a `std::vector` to manage such a big number of distinct values sounds a lot more reasonable!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a large number of values, simply put 'endl' on the same line as your output and loop through all of your data.  Such as:

```
for(int i = 0; i < numValues; ++i) {
    fout << values[i] << endl;
}
```

I'm not aware of a built-in way to automate this, but it's honestly not that much work to add line endings manually.

Comment: I doubt there is a way I can pass it a hundred different variables! I am inquiring because till today, I have been using the messy endl; and the freshmen [hs] who look at my code don't like it. in ifstream, I do not have to use a whitespace delimiter!

Comment: @yash101 Are you unable to store your data in an array?  That would make everything a lot easier.

Comment: I don't want to use an array because I need to be able to name the variables. Instead, I am using objects to store the variables. Most variables will be the same type but different values in the three parts of my program

Comment: -1 The code sample doesn't even resemble usage of a container (_array_), nor is this an answer for what the OP's asking for!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I admit I could have demonstrated a better loop the first time around.  However, my reason for including the loop at all was to show a better way to iterate over large numbers of values.  I realize that was not the format of the original code, but in most cases a loop like this is preferable over 100 lines of repetitious code.  Based on the OP's comments, he also seemed more concerned with automating the process than with removing `endl` in particular.

Comment: @yash101 You should definitely explain (1) why you do not want to use an array (2) what is particularly "messy" about endl. If you are somehow really really obligated to have 100 distinct variables instead of an array, well then your code is messy, not endl.

Comment: well, the variables are of all sorts, bools, ints, doubles, floats, strings, etc. That seems hard to do with an array. I have been storing the vars in objects because every part of my program has thresholding with different values, so the variables are the same.
This also allows me to take those classes and reuse them in different programs down the line!